# Why isn't the term *inequation* widely used in English?

Tags: terminology

Just as we distinguish between an equation and an identity (or equality), why don't we distinguish between an inequation and an inequality? We solve an inequation and we prove an inequality. In French they are clearly distinguished.

We say **solve this equation** and **prove this identity**, but (in English only AFAIK) we say **prove this inequality** and **solve this inequality** even though the term *inequation* already exists in English and is used in some document but the majority prefer to not use it.

For example the following is a question in an exam (in French) and the translated version, which doesn't seem to be a good translation.

[image]

[image]

«Utiliser l'inégalité $(x+1)^2\geq 0$ pour résoudre l'inéquation $\left(x^2+2x+1\right)(2x-5)\leq 0$»

Comparing the ngrams of inequation in English and in French, we see a big decline of its use between 1960 and 1977 followed by a small increase in the 80s. In French the frequency is almost the same between 1965 and 1985. Is there a reason for the decline between 1960 and 1977?

[image]
[image]

EDIT:

I've been told that the term "inequation" is widely used in the middle east and some Arab countries. It's used in some standardized exams in middle school, high school and technical/vocational schools. See for example the [center of educational research and development](https://www.crdp.org/curr-content-desc?id=1) in Lebanon.

Comment: @MichaelE2 In french, inégalité means inequality whereas inéquation means inequation.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I believe, but  just learned the word and searched around a bit, the point is that the problem like "Determine the set of all $x$ such that $\sin x \le 1/2$" would be referred to as "Solve the inequation $\sin x \le 1/2$."  The example "Résoudre l'inéquation $\sin^2 \theta \le 1/2$" is something I just found in  textbook online.  I am not quite sure how popular it actually is. But something like $\pi \le 3.2$ would be an inégalité and never an inéquation.

Comment: @MichaelE2 $a^2+b^2\geq 2ab$ is an inequality, true for all real numbers $a$ and $b$. $a^2-3a+2\geq 0$ is an inequation that need to be solved.

Comment: I have never seen a question say *prove this identity*.

Comment: Also, saying 'the word inequation already exists in English' is has a very different meaning to 'the word inequation already exists in French'. English is not in any way regulated. That someone out there uses the word is not the same as it being part of mainstream English (it is not).

Comment: Having different scales on your graphs is not really very helpful.

Comment: @JessicaB I'm trying to understand the decline of its use in english between the 60s and 70s not to compare the frequemcy in the 2 graphs. I know this term isn't part of mainstream english but it is used nevertheless and I think it should be used more ; there should be a clear distinction bewteen inequation and inequality just as we distinguish "prove this identity or formula or equality" and "solve this equation". BTW "prove this equation" is an abuse of language.

Comment: @BPP We would just say 'prove that:'.

Comment: @BPP Something that your ngram does not show is that the use of "inequation" has *always* been relatively insignificant.  [Comparing "inequality" to "inequation"](https://bit.ly/2Iww8Kl) is enlightening.  It is also worth noting that if you look at the ngram going back farther, the use of "inequation" rises sharply in the early 50s, before dropping off again.  You happen to have started your graph in a place where it makes it look like there is a steep decline, when what really appears to be happening is a regression to the historic mean.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I can't compare "inequality" to "inequation" in ngrams. "inequality" is used in politics, sociology, economy, philosophy, etc. not just in mathematics.

Comment: @BPP Okay... try [this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prove+the+inequality%2Cprove+the+inequation&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprove%20the%20inequality%3B%2Cc0), which adds the phrase "prove the ...".  You can change the verb, and get similar results ("solve" is kind of interesting).  I also think that you are asking the wrong question regarding the decline of "inequation."  The question is not "why did it decline?" but rather "why did it spike in the first place?"

Comment: @XanderHenderson Did you read my explanation of "inequation"? If you read it carefully you'll understand the need for this term. You can also read about it on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequation#Solving_inequations) or the more detailed [article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/In%C3%A9quation) in French.

Comment: @BPP I honestly *don't* see the need for the term "inequation".  I see that a few English authors draw a distinction between the two (though even the Wikipedia article you cite doesn't exactly give clarity on the exact nature of that distinction), and I see that the two terms are distinct in French.  I would counter by noting that "inequation" is much rarer in English (and *always* has been), we do perfectly well without the term "inequation", and that English is not French.

Comment: @XanderHenderson A little bit of improvement doesn't hurt. The article in french is a little bit more detailed, you can google-translate it. We can do without the words "equation", "identity" and "formula" and just use the word "equality" but it's better to have them, isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92745/discussion-between-xander-henderson-and-bpp).

Comment: FWIW, many mathematically educated native speakers of English [hold the opinion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30194/11619) that $x>0$ is *an inequality*, but $x\neq0$ is *an inequation*.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's wrong. It's not an opinion. Google "inequation".

Comment: @Paracosmiste Your accepted answer cites [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inequation.html), which gives the definition that Jyrki Lahtonen gave.

Comment: @jgon «...and mathworld does a horrible job explaining it »

Comment: @Paracosmiste, I don't see what the answerer's opinion of the source's definition has to do with it. The answerer clearly disagrees with mathworld's definition, but they are objectively wrong that mathworld does a horrible job explaining it. Mathworld is extremely clear with its definition. It's just not the one that the answerer would like.

Comment: @jgon It really does a bad job. Search "inequation" on google and see the results. Almost nobody use the "definition" of mathworld.

Comment: @Paracosmiste, even Wikipedia says that some authors take mathworld's definition. An explanation isn't bad because it's explaining a different concept than the one you have in mind, and definitions aren't bad because you'd prefer a different one. To me, inequation isn't an English word, but it's reasonable to define it as mathworld does, and it's reasonable to define it as Wikipedia does. You haven't made an argument for why one definition is preferable. Saying that it means something else in a different language is not convincing.

Comment: @jgon One definition is used a lot more than the others. Mathworld called $A\neq B$ an inequation. But $A\neq B$ is just the negation of $A=B$, it doesn't need a name. A better definition of inequation is given on wikipedia, in the accepeted answer and the linked sites. Whether people who downvoted that answer agree or not doesn't matter, people who use this term will continue to use it.

Comment: @Paracosmiste It strikes me that the Wikipedia definition doesn't agree with that presented in your question or the accepted answer either. Wikipedia defines it as a statement of inequality, which seems to have nothing to do with a distinction between proving and solving. What's more I'm skeptical that you can show that one definition is used more than the others by native English speakers (ESL speakers being likely to bias the sample) given that vanishingly few English speakers use the word at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have to disagree with the answers claiming that the word "inequation" isn't necessary in english or that it isn't widely used because "people" chose not to. The fact is that most english speakers don't know it exists and [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inequation.html) does a horrible job explaining it.

I taught mathematics in four languages. Of these four english was the most different in its terminologies and notations. For example we denote an open interval $]a,b[$ which is similar to the closed one $[a,b]$; in english they use $(a,b)$ for the open interval. That doesn't only cause unnecessary confusion with the pair (unordered couple) $(a,b)$ but also isn't compatible with the notations of geometry ($[AB]$ and $]AB[$ for segments and $(AB)$ for the line).

The same goes for many other notations and terminologies like a skew field not being a field, 5/8/2000 means "8 may 2000" instead of the international "5 august 2000". And of course the term "inequation" was one of them. The books published in US or UK never use this term; they use "inequality" to mean two different things. The books translated to english in other countries usually use such terms and terminologies.

The problem is that this term hasn't entered school books yet. If it didn't in french there wouldn't be many people using the term "inéquation"; that wouldn't mean that this word isn't necessary. So the necessity or importance of the word isn't correlated with the frequency of its use. If a curriculum reform introduced this term in schools, its use will grow exponentially at all levels. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688205/terminology-how-to-call-this-relation-inequality-inequation) on another site and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144959/how-to-solve-this-inequation?rq=1) where he had to use the inequality tag because there's no inequation tag until today [3 May 2019].

The image below is from the book *The A to Z of Mathematics* by Thomas Sidebotham.

[image]

Finally comparing the english wikipedia article with the french one, the deutsch or the català articles, you see much less explanations in english. So a student who consults wikipedia won't learn much. Other websites explain it better with examples like [this one](https://www.sangakoo.com/en/unit/first-degree-inequations) or [this one](https://www.bbc.com/bitesize/guides/zwgdb82/revision/3).

Comment: Well I just added the tag "inequation" to that site.

Comment: @BPP It's not clear to me what is the purpose of creating such tag when the tag (inequality) already exists. (Did you want to add it as a synonym of the other tag?) But that' probably a thing which should be discussed on [Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions) or in the [Tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50157608#50157608).

Comment: @Martin You may not use it but other may use it. (inequation) isn't synonym to inequality; see the accepted version or see the wikipedia article.

Comment: @BPP Since the discussion here is actually not that related to *this* question and is actually about tags on another Stack Exchange site, it would probably better to discuss the issue on that site's meta. I have already posted this question on Mathematics Meta to see what other users think about this: [Should there be distinction between the tags (inequation) and (inequality)?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30193) (And it is also a good place where you could clarify the purpose of the newly created tag.)

Comment: "does a horrible job explaining it" I am not sure that's the case. It explains a clearly, but give a different meaning to it.

Comment: Regarding German, in my opinion the word for inequality is just Ungleichung (and Gleichung is equation), and that's that. Other than that it's the same as in English in that no particular distinction is made. $7/5 \le \sqrt{2}$ is an Ungleichung and $x+2 \le x^2$ is also an Ungleichung.

Comment: In American schools, the notations for lines, line segments and rays are respectively $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$, $\overline{AB}$, $\overrightarrow{AB}$.

Comment: @jgon How do denote $[AB]$, $]AB[$, $[AB[$, $]AB]$ and $]AB)$ ?

Comment: EDIT: The tag "inequation" has been merged with "inequality" because some moderators "couldn't understand the difference".

Comment: @Paracosmiste, in Euclidean geometry in American schools, we do not use open/half open line segments.

Comment: @jgon But you use half open intervals. Anyway $\overrightarrow{AB}$ is a vector or a half-line?

Comment: @Paracosmiste Typically in Euclidean geometry, $\overrightarrow{AB}$ is a half-line, since vectors are typically not discussed in the treatment of synthetic geometry in high schools. Instead, vectors are discussed in the context of analytic geometry. There one would typically see something more like let $\vec{d}$ denote the vector from $A$ to $B$. Or even more likely, you might see something like let $\vec{d}$ denote the displacement as an object travels from $A$ to $B$. We do use half open intervals, yes. Also I'm not sure what $]AB)$ would be. (is that a ray open on the finite side?)

Comment: @jgon So $\overrightarrow{AB}$ could mean a vector and a half-line. I understand the arrow for vectors which are directed segments by why use it for half-line which aren't directed?  $[AB)$ is the half-line that starts at $A$  and continues indefinitely passing by $B$. If we remove $A$ from it we obtain $]AB)$.

Comment: @Paracosmiste, I would be fairly surprised to encounter $\overrightarrow{AB}$ to mean a vector in a high school geometry course, as I've already expressed. As for the other notation, that's what I assumed, but it isn't used here, so I was just guessing.

Comment: @Paracosmiste, half lines are directed. They are only infinite in one direction. The arrows on the line above the letters indicate if the line piece stops at the letter on that side or continues through infinitely far. As I mentioned before, open line segments aren't used in synthetic geometry in high schools here.

Comment: Your "8 May 2000" example isn't English. It's American. A different language, which confusingly has the same name.

Answer (score 14):

You ask "Why isn't the term *inequation* widely used in English?"

The answer, however tautological, is that the term isn't used in English because it isn't used in English.  Perhaps more usefully, remember that languages change and evolve as speakers of the language (for example) start using new words, stop using old words, alter pronunciation, and play with grammatical structure.  When a language possesses a word which is used infrequently, the answer to the question of *why* that word is used infrequently is typically "Because speakers of that language do not frequently require that word in order to communicate ideas to each other."

One important facet of language evolution is that you will almost never find two words which have exactly the same meaning.  If a language possesses two synonymous words, one of two things typically happens:  either the meanings of the two words diverge (for example, big, large, and huge all mean basically the same thing in English, but have different connotations), or one of the two words will fall out of favor (for example, the word "empathic" in English seems to be in the process of being replaced by "empathetic").

In English usage, the words "inequation" and "inequality" have nearly identical meanings.  Moreover, it appears that there are very few instances where a native speaker of English might want to draw a distinction between these two concepts.  As such, one of the two words is used quite a lot, while the other is used rarely.  We *can* draw distinctions between the two words (e.g. via the analogy "equality : equation :: inequality : inequation") and assert that the words have quite different meaning, but the fact of the matter is that most English speakers *don't* feel that distinction, and therefore do not require the word "inequation."

---

You also, secondarily, ask why the use of "inequation" went into decline in the mid-20th century.  I dispute that interpretation of events.  If you expand the time scale to cover the last 200 years, you get a very different picture:

[image]

First off, if you look at the vertical scale, it indicates that this word has *never* been all that common, even in the late 50s and early 60s when it hit it's peak.  More importantly, it appears to me that the word was hardly used *until* the late 50s, when usage spiked.  The decline after that is simply a return to normalcy.

I think that the more interesting question is "Why did the use of the term *inequation* appear to spike in the late 50s?"  A couple of hypotheses occur off the top of my head:

- The term has never been very common.  That spike could easily be the result of the word being used frequently by a very small number of authors.  The spike, then might represent the output of one or two people's careers:  a lot of publications early on, with fewer publications as they take on other duties.
- The use of the term might be related to the adoption of the "new math" curriculum.  It starts trending up a little bit early, but it is possible that the term was brought into vogue by new math advocates, and that the decline coincides with the decline of new math.
- (This is they hypothesis which I favor.) After WWII, tensions between the US and the USSR increased, and a great deal of emphasis was placed on mathematics and engineering education.  US institutions recruited a large number of European mathematicians in that time, many of whom were not native English speakers.  The spike may be due to their writing in English but with some of their own native vocabulary.  The decline could then be explained by acculturation, as well as the deaths and retirements of these European scholars.

---

Finally, because this website is about mathematics education and not (for example) English language usage, there is a mild pedagogical argument against using the term.

Every time a new term is introduced, you create extra cognitive work for your students.  The goal should be to introduce as little jargon and technical terminology as is necessary to understand the underlying concepts.  Certainly, there are times when we really need distinct words to describe things.  For example, the word *continuous* is very useful, as it hides a couple of distinct (though equivalent) definitions ($\varepsilon$-$\delta$? left- and right-limits agree with the function? etc.).  Still, it is a bit of vocabulary that students have to learn, and they struggle with it.  If some bit of jargon does not make future discourse easier, then it should probably be skipped.

In my own teaching, I typically try to avoid using the word "identity," and will typically use it interchangeably with "equality" and "equation" if I do happen to use it.  Moreover, I can typically avoid using any jargon by simply asking students to do what I want them to do.  For example, instead of asking them to prove an identity, I can simply give them the statement and ask them to prove it.  For example, I would write

> Show that $\sin(t)^2 + \cos(t)^2 = 1$ for any real number $t$.

instead of

> Prove the identity $\sin(t)^2 + \cos(t)^2 = 1$.

I *might* (depending on the class) finish this by stating "This formula (or equation or identity or statement) is called the 'Pythagorean identity'," but I can do that without ever explicitly defining the word "identity."

Comment: Did it come to your mind that it is rarely used just because very few people know it exists in the first place?

Comment: @BPP That isn't how languages work.  If there were a need for a word to describe the concept of an "inequation", then such a word would exist and its use would catch on.  Because the word is not widely used (nor is any alternative, aside from "inequality"), it seems that writers of English have not had much need to describe the concept.

Comment: No that's not always the case. You have an oversimplified model in mind. For example it's easier to say "$f$ is onto" than to say "$f$ is a surjection/is surjective". In this case there is no need for the new word "surjection" (and its derivatives) according to your simple model of language evolution.

Comment: Yes, it is a simplified model.  It does not explain *everything*.  You will notice that I hedged extensively above---you *almost* never find exact synonyms in natural language.  That does not mean that such things do not exit (consider "sofa" vs "couch").  However, lacking further evidence, the answer to your question is "Inequation is not used because people don't use inequation."  The word has not taken off.  There is no hole in the language which needs to be patched by the term.

Comment: This is one of the best answers I have seen on this site.

Comment: @Xander  I have [recommended that you nominate](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/615/238) yourself to run in the upcoming election for the moderator position available.  If you'd prefer, I can delete my recommendation, or you can respond to it in any way that you see fitting.

Answer (score 2):

Your premise is not entirely true. We do distinguish between an equation and an identity in English *sometimes*, but most of the time we use 'equation' for both. 'Identity' is only really used on 'special occasions'. In particular, students are only likely to come across the term in the context of 'trig identities' such as $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$. There are no notable instances of 'identities with inequality signs' that students come across, so there is no reason to use different terms to distinguish them.

Comment: I've rarely seen an identity referred to as an equation; we call it a formula but not an equation. $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$ is an algebraic identity, $\left(u(x)v(x)\right)'=u'(x)v(x)+u(x)v'(x)$ ...  Identities are everywhere not only in trigonometry.

Comment: That isn't an answer, it should be a comment.

Comment: @BPP I started writing a comment, but then realised what I was writing *is* an answer. The question is why we don't distinguish inequality and inequation. The answer is that we make so little distinction between equation and identity that there's not really a good reason to do so.

Comment: @BPP Also, I have never heard those other identities referred to as such. I'm not saying there are no other identities, only that we don't point them out as such so students very rarely hear the term in any other context.

Comment: There are actually some notable inequalities (in English).  For example, in functional analysis, there are the Cauchy-Schartz and Minkowski inequalities, as well as many Sobolev inequalities.  Oh!  and the Poincare inequality.  That being said, there are vanishingly few important inequalities that appear before graduate school, so perhaps this is what is meant when you say that there are few inequalities which students routinely come across.  I have upvoted this answer, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

So equations are statements of equality that evaluate as true or false.
Inequality statements are statements of inequality that evaluate true or false.
At the point I introduce inequality statements the symbol in the middle becomes part of a larger set of the language.

So equations are a subset of statements where the truth comparison is done on equality. 
When we start introducing inequality statements we are building the larger set, though we may not explicitly state it the beginning.

I do try to emphasize that statements are a test and the symbol is the type of test you are doing.

I think this may the reason we don't have a separate word in use for inequality statements. At the point they are introduced we have taken the idea of equality statements and are talking about the more general concept of statements.

Though I would say we do imply it more than state this idea. So it may be good to focus language on statement and the type of statements we create.

I am really interested in ideas on language choice and pedagogy. Thus I am very interested in the the ideas behind this question and what others have seen and done.